# Capture image is not able to store in SD card?

Tags: android, button, android-emulator

when i click button camera is capture the image but not able to save in SD card.please check this code.if i did any mistake

> `
>           ImgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

```
    BtnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    BtnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
   private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"image.jpeg");
    File myDir = new File(root + "/sdcard/");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpeg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
}
}`
```

Comment: call finish() should led you back to previous activity. SHould you not leave to the user to click back button

Comment: How to enabled or disable phone back button ?

Comment: not possible to disable back button

Comment: But how to enabled ?  any method ?

Comment: You can override OnbackPressed. But you should rhink of re-designing rather than workaround

Comment: With using OnbackPressed ..it is possible to make..phone button enabled ?

Comment: re-think and re-design your flow. Read about navigation design guidelines in the docs

Comment: why person voted negative ..i think its not waste question...

Comment: you want to enable/disable back button in your activity OR you want your android virtual device back button enabled/disabled in general?

Comment: @ArnavM  yes i want to do like this ?

Comment: @17Coder read my edited comment again. choose your question

Comment: @ArnavM  android virtual device back button enabled/disabled in general?    how ?

Comment: On an emulator, you can press `esc`, which is the equivalent of a back button on an actual phone, I think.

Answer (score 1):

When the back button is pressed, the current activity's [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method is called. The default behavior is to finish the activity. You shouldn't need to do anything to enable this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to AVD manager.
- edit your device.
- choose skin with dynamic hardware controls.
- uncheck hardware keyboard present(or Escape in keyboard=Back button)